# Prometheus - combining two alerts with and and vectoring

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

we have several alerts and we want to combine these alerts to one big alert for CPU, Memory and Disk IO.

For example:

```
rules:
  - alert: OutOfMemory
    annotations:
      description: "Node memory is filling up (< 5% left)\n VALUE = {{ $value }}"
      summary: Out of memory (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
    expr: node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes * 100 < 5
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: warning
```

and

```
  - alert: HighCpuLoad
    annotations:
      description: "CPU load is > 90%\n VALUE = {{ $value }}"
      summary: High CPU load (instance {{ $labels.instance }})
    expr: 100 - (avg by(instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100) > 80
    for: 5m
    labels:
      severity: warning
```

We can't figure out how those alerts would look like combined with the operator "and" plus vectoring. Can someone help us out here?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the [vector matching instruction](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) which, in brief and in simple cases such as yours, translates to *indicate which labels should match on both sides of the operator*.

In the case of the node exporter it would be:

```
(<OutOfMemory expression>) AND ON(instance) (<HighCpuLoad expression>)
```

From a usability point of view, I would rather have multiple alerts which are not sent to your alerting system (use a black hole in alertmanager) and then use the `ALERTS` metric to trigger you *big* alert. It will allow you to have:

- more simple and more rich expressions (you could trigger alert if 4/5 are firing or have some `OR` clause)
- looking at a dashboard, you will know which issues are exactly firing
- different `for`statements - you may not want to have the same `for` for high cpu and memory outage.

I have not tested it but it would look like the following:

```
rules:
  - alert: NodeInTrouble
    expr: sum(ALERTS{alertname=~"OutOfMemory|HighCpuLoad"}) BY (instance) == 2
    for: 1m
    labels:
      severity: warning
```